# Rails app which uses bootstrap 3.3.6 doesn't have viewport in head

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

EDIT-2> It wasn't working on my homepage because I was using a custom template for the homepage, if not signed in.

---

I've created a Rails app using Bootstrap 3.3.6, Rails 5.1.5.

I have bootstrap installed and it seems to be working, but my site isn't responsive. However, if I go to the Browser, and press F12 to open developer tools and manually add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the `<head>`, then it becomes responsive.

However, it's not automatically present in the head, even if i add it to the `<head>` in `application.html.erb`.

Also, if i press F12 to enter/close dev tools (in chrome), then it shows the responsive view for a split second.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'has_friendship', :git => 'git://github.com/Hawry/has_friendship.git', :ref => '5f4675f'
gem 'administrate'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
```

**Application.css.scss:**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "cover.scss";
@import "user.scss";
@import "categories.scss";
@import "forum.scss";
@import "goals.scss";
@import "chat.scss";
```

**Application.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Anything added here needs to also be added to the index/homepage partial, -->
    <!--as the workaround to escape container from application on homepage-->
    <% if action_name == "choose_interests" || action_name == "set_profile" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/sign_up_nav' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <% if action_name == "choose_interests" || action_name == "set_profile" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/sign_up_footer' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree ./channels
```

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want it to be responsive, and when you add the `meta name="viewport"` line, it becomes responsive. But I don't see that in your `application.html.erb`. So: add it in to your template and you should be good to go. That's what bootstrap docs say, too: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working on my homepage because I was using a custom template for the homepage, if not signed in.

Lessons learned:

Check multiple pages / signed in/out..